# How do I detect when any button is pressed without writing individual code for each button in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to coding and currently I am coding a VB.net Windows Form Hangman game. I have 26 letter buttons that when pressed I would like the text of them (A,B,C,Etc.) to be put into a Text box so the player knows what letter they have inputted and they can then submit their guess. However, so far the only way I have figured out how to detect when any of the buttons is pressed is by writing the code individually for each button which looks very messy and inefficient. I was wondering if it was possible to detect when any of the buttons is pressed (And know which one) without writing code for each individual button?

This is only for 4 of the buttons so I have to do this 22 more times for what I want to do and more for any additional buttons:

Current Code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Button3.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Button4.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Button5.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Button6.Text
End Sub`
```

This is the game when run. When any of the letter buttons are pressed I would like them to be detected. The text box on the right shows the button that is pressed:(https://hi.stack.imgur.com/92sDy.png)

I hope someone can help,
thank you in advance,
Georgitzu

Comment: Create just one event handler and then hook up each of your buttons to the same event.  You will be able to identify the button pressed from the sender parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I used the code suggested from the post Mike wrote to execute this and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic idea ...

' assign all button click events to the same routine

Private Sub buttonHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click, Button1.Click .... Button26.Click

' create a generic button object to handle the button clicked

Dim obtn as Button = CType(sender, Button)

' display the text

TextBox2.Text = obtn.Text

Hope this helps,
Mike